# Couchbase "Servers Down: 1" error On MAC os

Tags: macos, couchbase, server-error

So i started using couchbase a while back. For some reason after updating to v 3.0 and restarting my machine my one and only server is Down. For good. Cant open my project which is JSF based. At first i could access it but now it only gives an error. I debuged it and found out my couchbase server was and still is down. I dont really know how to debug(the couchbase server) it in order to get it up again. I tried a fix that a friend told me : to uninstall couchbase completely which i did, only catch being the fact that ~Library / Application Support / couchbase wasnt a valid directory. Still erased all data that i could find. But for some reason, the server is still being stored in my machine and its still giving me the DOWN error. Can anyone tell me how to delete or restore my local server? Or completely uninstall couchbase server?

Cant rebalance, server node is on PEND

Much obliged.

Couchbase Version 3.0.0-1209-rel

Comment: I would recommend posting this question on the Couchbase forums. You should also include logs so someone can diagnose the issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I did.

Comment: I found that version `4.5.x` doesn't work on Mac OS X Sierra, but `4.6.x` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue where my server was pending and I couldn't do anything about it.

I resolved the problem by:

1. quitting Couchbase Server
2. deleting the Couchbase folder from `/Users/<yourname>/Application Support`
3. starting up Couchbase Server again
4. using all of the defaults for setup

You could try this then restore your data into the `Application Support/Couchbase` directory.

Comment: On Yosemite, I don't have an `Application Support` directory.

Comment: According to http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/mac-uninstall.html what you really want is `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Couchbase`

Comment: I followed the instructions here but unchecked "`Enable Replication`" during setup to solve the issue.